# What's an elegant way for one loop iteration to affect another?

Tags: python, text-processing

I needed to process a config file just now. Because of the way it was generated, it contains lines like this:

```
---(more 15%)---
```

The first step is to strip these unwanted lines out. As a slight twist, each of these lines is followed by a blank line, which I also want to strip. I created a quick Python script to do this:

```
skip_next = False
for line in sys.stdin:
    if skip_next:
        skip_next = False
        continue    
    if line.startswith('---(more'):
        skip_next = True
        continue    
    print line,
```

Now, this works, but it's more hacky than I'd hoped. The difficulty is that when looping through the lines, we want the content of one line to affect the subsequent line. Hence my question: What's an elegant way for one loop iteration to affect another?

Comment: Any reason you can't just discard the blank lines independently? I mean, I can't imagine they're any more meaningful in other parts of the file. (though using Python, who knows? The whitespace might be meaningful...)

Comment: @Telastyn - in this case, that would work. I'm interested in other ideas though as I see similar problems from time to time, and have never come up with a better solution than boolean variables like "skip_next"

Comment: you can use grep and regex to filter things out, might be easier than trying it with python

Comment: @omouse: ...and then he would have two problems.  That saying's become idiomatic for a reason.

Comment: Do you want to strip *just* blanks before '---(more' or is it ok to *all* blank lines?  If it is the latter, then you can make things much easier just by ignoring both individually.

Comment: @omouse - grep treats each line independently. There are minor dependencies between lines, so this pretty much rules grep out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to do this is with `itertools.tee`, which allows you to split the iterator into two.  You can then advance one iterator by one step, putting one iterator one line ahead of the other.  You can then zip up the two iterators and look at both the previous line and the current line at each step of the `for` loop (I use `izip_longest` so it doesn't drop the last line):

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest
in1, in2 = tee(sys.stdin, 2)
next(in2)
for line, prevline in izip_longest(in1, in2, fillvalue=''):
    if line.startswith('---(more') or prevline.startswith('---(more'):
        continue
    print line
```

This could also be done as an equivalent generator expression:

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest
in1, in2 = tee(sys.stdin, 2)
next(in2)
pairs = izip_longest(in1, in2, fillvalue='')
res = (line for line, prevline in pairs
       if not line.startswith('---(more') and not prevline.startswith('---(more'))
for line in res:
    print line
```

Or you could use `filter`, which allows you to drop iterator items when a condition is not true.

```
from itertools import tee, izip_longest
in1, in2 = tee(sys.stdin, 2)
next(in2)
pairs = izip_longest(in1, in2, fillvalue='')
cond = lambda pair: not pair[0].startswith('---(more') and not pair[1].startswith('---(more')
res = filter(cond, pairs)
for line in res:
    print line
```

If you are willing to go outside the python standard library, the `toolz` package makes this even easier.  It provides a `sliding_window` function, which allows you to split up an iterator such as `a b c d e f` into something like `(a,b), (b,c), (c,d), (d,e), (e,f)`.  This does basically the same thing as the `tee` approach above, it just combined three lines into one:

```
from toolz.itertoolz import sliding_window
for line, prevline in sliding_wind(2, sys.stdin):
    if line.startswith('---(more') or prevline.startswith('---(more'):
        continue
    print line
```

you could additionally use `remove`, which is basically the opposite of `filter`, to drop the items without needing a `for` loop:

```
from tools.itertoolz import sliding_window, remove
pairs = sliding_window(2, sys.stdin)
cond = lambda x: x[0].startswith('---(more') or x[1].startswith('---(more')
res = remove(cond, pairs)
for line in res:
    print line
```

Answer (score 11):

The reason this feels awkward is that you're fundamentally Doing It Wrong.  A `for` loop is supposed to be a sequential iteration over each element of a series.  If you're doing something that's calling `continue` without even looking at the current element, based on something that happened in a previous element of a series, you're breaking that basic abstraction.  You're then introducing awkwardness with the extra moving parts required to take care of the square-peg-in-round-hole solution you're setting up.

Instead, try keeping the action close to the condition that causes it.  We know that a `for` loop is just syntactic sugar for a special case of a `while` loop, so let's use that.  Pseudocode, since I'm not familiar with Python's I/O subsystem:

```
while not sys.stdin.eof: //or whatever
    line = sys.stdin.ReadLine()
    if line.startswith('---(more'):
        sys.stdin.ReadLine() //read the next line and ignore it
        continue    
    print line
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your thinking, although I'm not so keep on calling ReadLine() in this code. Turns out you can call sys.stdin.next() to get a similar effect, while still using "for line in sys.stding" which seems pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we can skip a line by manually advancing the iterator. This results in code that is somewhat similar to Mason Wheeler's solution, but still uses the iteration syntax. There is a related Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592798/how-can-i-skip-the-current-item-and-the-next-in-a-python-loop):

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('---(more'):
        sys.stdin.next()
        continue    
    print line,
```